# Why do we need intent lock?

Tags: database, concurrency

In a database, we would not like the table to be dropped during we are modifying a row in this table. Per my understanding,  a read lock on table + a write lock on row when write a row in table should be enough(based on that a write lock is needed when drop the table),  why do we need a intent lock in this case?  seems many databases using intent lock which confused me very much. I think pthread_rwlock should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the conclusions today is "**intent lock can lock a parent node AND all its children nodes in a read only mode in a cheaper/safer way**".

Take an example for making a table read only case, how to lock it in S-X mode?

1. We lock the table in S mode, then user still can modify the rows with S(table) + W(row) way.   to avoid that, we need to lock every row in a S mode to make sure rows will not be updated.  The cost is so huge, and it has a bug that user can insert new rows as well. -- cost too much and not safe.
2. We lock the table in X mode,   How other can read the rows (S on table + S on row), no way, since mode_X on table blocked MODE_S on table. That's not read only.

The right solution with the intent lock is:

Lock the table in MODE_S.  that's all!

any intention to modify the rows needs to take a MODE_IX lock on the table, but it is blocked by MODE_S.  the solution is cheap/efficient and safe!

Answer (score 12):

I read [here](http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2016/05/16/why-do-we-need-intent-locks-in-sql-server/) that they only exists for performance. Imagine you want to drop a table but you would have to check for every row if its locked or not - that would be time consuming, and you would have to lock every row that you checked.

Heres a citation from the blog post:

> From a technical perspective the Intent Locks are not really needed by
>   SQL Server. They have to do with performance optimization. Let’s have
>   a look on that in more detail. With an Intent Lock SQL Server just
>   indicates at a higher level within the Lock Hierarchy that you have
>   acquired a Lock somewhere else. A Intent Shared Lock tells SQL Server
>   that there is a Shared Lock somewhere else. A Intent Update or Intent
>   Exclusive Lock does the same, but this time SQL Server knows that
>   there is an Update Lock or an Exclusive Lock somewhere. It is just an
>   indication, nothing more.
>
> But how does that indication help SQL Server with performance
>   optimization? Imagine you want to acquire an Exclusive Lock at the
>   table level. In that case, SQL Server has to know if there is an
>   incompatible lock (like a Shared or Update Lock) somewhere else on a
>   record. Without Intent Locks SQL Server would have to check every
>   record to see if an incompatible lock has been granted.
>
> But with an Intent Shared Lock on the table level, SQL Server knows
>   immediately that a Shared Lock has been granted somewhere else, and
>   therefore an Exclusive Lock can’t be granted at the table level.
>   That’s the whole reason why Intent Locks exist in SQL Server: to allow
>   efficient checking if an incompatible lock exists somewhere within the
>   Lock Hierarchy. Quite easy, isn’t it?

Answer (score 0):

> read lock on table + a write lock on row

This would break meaning of the `read lock` on the table.

Assume concurrent SELECT operation, which expects *unmodified table* during execution. This operation will take **read lock on the table** ... and it will **succeed** in your implementation. This is bad, as *table is actually modified* during row modification.

Instead, follow locks combination is used for modify row in the table:

```
IX(Intent eXclusive) on table + X(eXclusive, similar to "write lock") on row
```

This combination is *compatible* (that is, can be executed concurrently) with modification of another row, but it is **incompatible** with

```
S(Share, similar to "read lock") on table
```

used by SELECT.

Locks compatibility table can be found, e.g., on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_granularity_locking).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, @Tsyvarev.   Do you have any code snippet to show how to implement a intent lock?  As for simple read/write lock,  it is pthread_rwlock_xxx.  do we have some utilities in Linux for intent lock?    also, when intent lock is better than RWLock.   Because of some cheaper operation,  better   granularity?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how intent locks are implemented. As I know, databases are main users of that functionality. Having really large tables granularity is very important.